# In Sutton & Barto, what is meaning of weight given to actual final return after termination in the Delta return? (equation 12.3)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

The equation 12.3, in the book RL An Intro by Sutton & Barto, is shown below with its "diagramatic" explanation in figure 12.2:

[image]

Once the episode has terminated at time T, what's the meaning of adding this constant value $\lambda^{T-t-1}G_t$?

If they wanted to add this constant just to conserve the "Area = 1" property, why not rethinking about the constant $1-\lambda$ without having to add a constant to compensate for the less area? Does not adding this additional constant $\lambda^{T-t-1}G_t$ at the end has any severe mathematical/practical implications?